Non-EU student - which visa category should I apply under for my summer project (German visa)?
I am currently an undergraduate student in India, and I have been invited in the summer for a research collaboration (technically a summer internship) to a German institute. I have been provided with a scholarship contract, and an invite letter, but no Bundesagentur für Arbeit. I have been instructed by the supervisor to apply under the guest scientist/researcher category, but does that apply to me?
Additionally, I applied earlier in the month under the student internship category and got rejected - would it be okay for me to change categories and submit the same documents?
Edit: BTW- We applied under the internship category without the work permit, did not work. Always ask the administration directly, or clarify all details with the embassy.

You are invited to research collaboration so guest researcher seems appropriate. But for the final question: your application was rejected: what they wrote? Same document? Check the documents you need to provide: different category may requires different documents. -- take it as part of your research project: many researchers need to find out permissions/documents/etc. (and immigration part is the most easy because it is much more documented: not only researchers need them).

What was the reason for the earlier refusal? Submitting the same documents for a new category visa application as you did for a recently refused application sounds like a recipe for another refusal to me.

Rejection and refusal are two different things @Traveller

@GiacomoCatenazzi it was rejected on the basis of the lack of work permit. I am an undergraduate with no degree, and limited research experience, hence the most applicable category seems to be internship/training visa.

@SaranshSharma I’m fully aware of that, thank you. The wording of the question implies that what the OP describes as ‘rejection’ was in fact ‘refusal’.

Was it a refusal or a rejection @S.K.

The proper visa category mainly depends on the nature of the project and occupation. In other words, the fact that you do not qualify for a guest researcher visa doesn't mean it's not the right category, it means the institute is not allowed to hire you for this position. If they cannot get you a work permit for an internship visa, I am not sure that there is any visa category that would allow an undergraduate to come to Germany for a short research project.


I have been instructed by the supervisor to apply under the guest scientist/researcher category, but does that apply to me?

If he or she means a Visa for research under § 18d AufenthG and EU directive 2016/801 then you are right that you do not seem to qualify without a PhD or graduate degree. At the same time, an internship visa may require a work permit. If the research institute is unable to help you get one, they may not be allowed to hire you.

Visa rejections and refusals are two different things. Your visa rejection clearly means that the category you applied was not valid for you hence your application was not complete , as instructed by your peer,  you should be applying for guest scientist / visiting scholar  if you satisfy these conditions
Does this category apply to you?

If you intend to do PhD or PostDoc studies in Germany and have obtained a work contract as “student assistant” or “scientific assistant” (“studentische Hilfskraft”), please refer to the information on studies visa.

If a Bachelor Degree is your highest academic qualification, please hand in your work contract instead of a hosting agreement.


Source Germany Official Link

I don’t have a bachelor’s degree, so I assume I do not fall under this category at all.
